# WPF DynamicResource does not update anything

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamicresource

i have a problem that was asked here, but given solutions didn't help.
I want to change background color of MainWindow's `Grid` from another window throught App global resources. The problem is, than i change `backBrush` dynamically, nothing happens. Moreover color initially is transparent. I tried different approaches of setting value in resources, like `Application.Current.Resources["key"] = new_value` and 
`MainGrid.SetResourceReference(Grid.BackgroundProperty, "key")` but nothing helps.

What am i doing wrong?

***Apps resources looks like this:***

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="backColor" R="255" G="0" B="255"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

***Troubled part of MainWindow:***

```
<Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="backBrush" Color="{DynamicResource backColor}"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid
        Name="MainGrid"
        Background="{DynamicResource backBrush}">
```

***Code, corresponding to change in color:***

```
this.Resources.Remove("backBrush");
this.Resources.Add("backBrush", 
                    new SolidColorBrush { Color = 
                        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["backColor"] });
MainGrid.SetResourceReference(Grid.BackgroundProperty, "backBrush");
```

*I also tried set color like this:*

```
Color newColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["backColor"];
Application.Current.Resources["backBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush { Color = newColor };
```

Comment: Bind the Grid's Background to a view model property.

Comment: Binding does not work either. Binded background color is always null and does not change if brush was changed

Comment: @Clemens also, if i change DynamicResource to StaticResource, colors still will remain transparent

Comment: I mean a view model property of type Brush with change notification, e.g. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Bind it like `Background="{Binding MyBackgroundBrush}"`.

Comment: I made changes, so now DynamicResource internally working, but nothing changes on screen :^(

New code:

`<Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="backBrush" Color="White"/>
</Window.Resources>`

`<Grid
        Name="MainGrid"
        Background="{DynamicResource backBrush}">`

And backcode looks like
`((SolidColorBrush)Resources["backBrush"]).Color =
 (Color)Application.Current.Resources["backColor"];`

Comment: @Clemens thank you, il try in a second

Comment: @Clemens simple `Background="{Binding MyBrush}"` doesn't work either. Maybe i miss the point...

Comment: That's WPF data binding. There should be an instance of the view model in the DataContext of the view. If you want to bind directly to a view model resource: `Background="{Binding MyBrush, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}"`

Comment: @Clemens im only beginner in wpf and didn't try to understand MVVM yet, so concrete example would be very helpful, because i do not understand, what type into `Source={}` . Sorry for bothering

Comment: This solution doesnt work either. Maybe my mistake is more subtle, so i cant see, what im doing wrong.

Thats how main code looks now:

[MainWindow.xaml -- main window markup](http://paste.org.ru/?6ilqdb) ,
[MainWindow.xaml.cs -- backcode for main window](http://paste.org.ru/?h0hsbf) ,
[ChangeBackColor.xaml.cs -- window which is called to change value of background](http://paste.org.ru/?mg4xjv)

Comment: Ok sorry, there is a simple bug. You forget to set the Color's alpha value. By default it is zero, but should certainly be `A="255"`

Comment: Mate, you saved my day! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the Color's alpha value, which is zero by default:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="backColor" R="255" G="0" B="255" A="255"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now you simply change the dynamic Brush resource by

```
Resources["backBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(
    (Color)Application.Current.Resources["backColor"]);
```